# Could not sign in Google account on android emulator with react-native app

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, gmail

I have react-native app, and it works thru Google account. And when i launch my app on android emulator i can not sign in Google account. Get an error: "There was a problem communicating with Google servers. Try again later".
My steps to reproduction:

- Reinstalled app and android emulator.
- Cleaned app and emulator cache.
- Checked different emulators model with different API.
- Tried to sign in Google account in android emulator from google chrome, from Settings => Accounts => Add Account => Google.

And all this steps is not working for me. Every time the same situation: the process of loading, spinner is launching about a minute, and after get an error: "Could not sign in". Can somebody help me please.

[image]

Comment: Guys, i have found the decision. The problem was my emulator was not connected to internet. My step was: 

1. Check environment emulator path and make sure it is like this:
MacOS:
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
Windows:
C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator
2.Check your available emulators list:
emulator -list-avds
3.Run your available emulator with dns server set to 8.8.8.8:
emulator @{YourEmulator} -dns-server 8.8.8.8
And after you can get access to Google from your android emulator.

Answer (score 4):

i have found the decision. The deal is my emulator was not connected to internet. My step was:

1. Check environment emulator path and make sure it is like this -
   MacOS: ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator, Windows: C:\Users%Username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator.
2. Check your available emulators list: emulator -list-avds.
3. Run your available emulator with dns server set to 8.8.8.8: emulator @{YourEmulator} -dns-server 8.8.8.8. And after you can get access to Google from your android emulator.

Comment: I pulled my hair out for an hour before I seen this answer. I was sceptical, but it solved my issue!

Comment: This does not work for me, using the Android emulator from Visual Studio 2022

Comment: I mean the first you need to check the name of your emulators in step 2, put this command to terminal: emulator -list-avds Then you need to put the name of your launched emulator, that you have checked on the previous step 2, to another command in terminal from step 3: emulator <put here your emulator name>  -dns-server 8.8.8.8

Comment: It did not work for me too. I am using Android Studio. But I believe my network proxy could be blocking the request.

Comment: @RohitSingh any luck? Pls see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74839322/could-not-sign-in-to-accounts-google-com-from-android-emulator