# Could not sign in to accounts.google.com from android emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-emulator

I am trying to setup an android emulator for local testing. I am working with Firebase Auth and other Firebase services. However, I noticed that the emulators that I am creating are unable to connect to accounts.google.com. I tried to sign in to google using my app, playstore and also from the device settings but all of these failed with the following:

```
2022-12-18 00:23:22.624 10270-10373/? E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
2022-12-18 00:23:22.643 10270-10270/? E/Auth: [MinuteMaid, MinuteMaidActivity] Error from MinuteMaidFragment: SSL error
```

[image]

My emulator specs are as below

> Pixel 3a API 33 Android Tiramisu Google Play | x86_64

I have the exact same emulator in another machine and it works fine on it. But that machine is too slow to work on.

My IDE is as below

> Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

I have also tried Android without Google Play but that also fails with the same error.

I don't think it is a network issue as I can use Google Search from the emulator and I can also login to all other websites from the machine where I am trying to set this. Despite this I have followed the steps in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62640178/1140783 but that did not work.

**NOTE**

I am seeing various different errors in logcat and I am not sure which is related to the problem of signing in. Here is one such exception:

```
2022-12-18 00:40:43.732 10270-10270/? E/Auth: [MinuteMaid, MinuteMaidActivity] Error from MinuteMaidFragment: SSL error
2022-12-18 00:40:44.806 1063-1509/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to access APN settings
    at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.checkPermissionForApnTable(TelephonyProvider.java:4997)
```

So how can I get accounts.google.com working in the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I updated the internal storage of my emulator. As a solution I simply deleted the emulator and created a new one and it worked.

PS - I was connected to internet and facing no issue internet setting.